# Twitter API using httr and GET

Tags: r, api, rest, twitter

I am trying to get tweets using Twitter API (I know about packages that allows you to collect tweets, but for my task i need to use their own API).

I set up my application and have credentials. But I am stuck at `GET` stage:

I am using [this](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/rules-and-filtering/build-standard-queries) to build my query, but the problem is in the token I guess...

```
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)

twitter_token <- create_token(
  app = appname,
  consumer_key = key,
  consumer_secret = secret)

url<-"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=rstats&src=typed_query"


res=GET(url, add_headers(
  'Authorization'=paste("Bearer ", twitter_token))
)
```

The error I am getting is

```
Error in as.vector(x, "character") : 
  cannot coerce type 'environment' to vector of type 'character'
```

how can I make it work? Pleeease!!!!
searched forums/twitter

Comment: even when I get the actual token using twitter_token[["credentials"]][["oauth_token"]]

and replace it in


res=GET(url, add_headers(
  Authorization=paste("Bearer ", "REALTOKENFROMCOPYANDPASTE"))
)
I get 401 error...


Please help!!!

Answer (score 2):

it worked!!!

```
app_keys <- openssl::base64_encode(paste0(key, ":", secret))

r <- httr::POST("https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token",
                httr::add_headers(Authorization = paste0("Basic ", app_keys)),
                body = list(grant_type = "client_credentials"))
bearer <- httr::content(r, encoding = "UTF-8")

url<-"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=rstats&src=typed_query"


res=GET(url, add_headers(
  Authorization=paste0("Bearer ", bearer$access_token))
)
```